# Using Semaphores in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having this problem where my database entries are not writing to my table in the correct order. I figured it was because they were entering asynchronously. Therefore, I tried to put them in a function that would synchronize the queries. I came up with the following:

```
function synchronizedInsert($userID, $pid, $pic, $xCoord, $newLine, $drawingColor)
{
    $semRes = sem_get(123321, 1, 0666, 1);

    if(sem_acquire($semRes))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cbmarker.annot_test (userid, project_id, image, date, coords, newLine, color)
                VALUES (" . $userID . "," . $pid . ",'". $pic . "', NOW()," . $xCoord . "," . $newLine . ",'" . $drawingColor . "')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        sem_release($semRes);   
    }
}
```

When I don't use semaphores and have only the query in my function

```
function synchronizedInsert($userID, $pid, $pic, $xCoord, $newLine, $drawingColor)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cbmarker.annot_test (userid, project_id, image, date, coords, newLine, color)
            VALUES (" . $userID . "," . $pid . ",'". $pic . "', NOW()," . $xCoord . "," . $newLine . ",'" . $drawingColor . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

then the funcion works but the I'm back to the problem of the entries entering in the wrong order. When I add the semaphores, the entries don't enter my table and my console gives me the error "GET ... 500 (Internal Sever Error)". Am I using the semaphores incorrectly or is there something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using semaphores to control the write ordering in the database, especially from PHP. What you should do is record the time of the receipt of record as a field and sort the DB data accordingly. This is all of course assuming that you don't have some other strange configuration on the database side.

Comment: Don't use mysql. It's deprecated. You should be using mysqli.

Comment: You can always 'serialize' updates in the database by using explicit locking of the database data. see 'select for update of', 'lock table in {various} mode' etc. And ensure that you use 'database transactions'